# click a select, but it should open only give a alternative alert

Tags: jquery, select, click

HI,
I added a event for when clicking on a select box, and i want  to have it that the select box shouldn't even open, but only open my event i created on click.
any ideas?

Comment: It's not possible. Whether a `select` box opens it's drop down is outside the scope of the web browser and the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution but works :)

```
$('#sel').focus(function() {
    this.blur();
    window.focus();
});

$('#sel').click(function(){
alert('Clicked but did not open');
});
```

K